# Remove rows that have common index/indices from two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following sample dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1:

index    forts
cherry    0.65
apple     0.85
mangoes   0.1
bananas   0.7
grapes    0.88

df2:

index    forts
cherry    0.35
peaches   0.45
mangoes   0.14
vanilla   0.57
straws    0.89
```

Seeing that both DataFrames have cherry and mangoes as common indices, despite having different values under the first column, I still want df1 to remove common indices from df2, and to do the same to df2, and keep them separate.

```
print(df1[(df1['forts']!=df2['forts'])].dropna(how='all'))
```

does not work, as it looks for duplicates based on index and column value

The final df1 and df2 should look like the following:

```
df1:

index    forts
apple     0.85
bananas   0.7
grapes    0.88 

df2:

index    forts
peaches   0.45
vanilla   0.57
straws    0.89
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df1=df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
df2=df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [symmetric_difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.symmetric_difference.html) between the two indices and reindex on that, and [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) :

```
difference = df1.index.symmetric_difference(df2.index)

#reindex and dropna :
df1 = df1.reindex(difference).dropna()
df2 = df2.reindex(difference).dropna()
```